# .net upgrade assistant added net7.0-windows for asp.net MVC webapplication during migration

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I used .net upgrade assistant tool convert my webapplication with asp.net MVC with .cshtml views of .net framework 4.8 to migrate to .net 7 then the tool included .net 7-windows as the target framework. this is the same case for projects of type library .
but my application is not using WPF or windows forms.

Tool suggested webapp first and automatically WPF and added above.

I agree output type is console application.
But when I am not sure if
.net7.0-windows
because when I created new webapplication it

So, I removed window and changed to .net6.0. and builded the migrated webapp, I got below error --

Error details -NETSDK1136
The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets  line - 146

above error is for all project including library and startup project, I see same error referring to same line 146 for all projects. Please let me know what can be done. I followed steps mentioned on the .net upgrade assistant on Microsoft website. My present project is not using WPF.

my application is not using WPF.

I request you please help as this is not on my project but at sdk level. I am not sure if this may any deployment issues in production on cloud environments

I removed windows from target framework. I changed to .net 6.0.

how to avoid above mentioned SDK error. It should not be problem  if we are deploying in different envs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root Cause: When I ran upgarde-assistant, it suggested WPF since there are windows specific dependencies. I removed all nugets which are widnows dependent and all dlls which are windows dependent. then it is migrated to .net6.0 target framework.